# Moving from JAVA setAutoCommit(false) to nodejs knex (SQL Server)

Tags: java, node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I'm writing application server for the company that I'm working for...
We are using `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` in another server application that is written in Java,
and I'm looking for doing it in nodejs.
In Java app We are using it like this :

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// SQL INSERT #1
// SQL INSERT #2
// SQL UPDATE #1
// SQL INSERT #3
// SQL INSERT #4
// SQL UPDATE #2

conn.commit();
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

In nodejs if I would do the same thing what I have to do?
I thought of sth like this but I don't know if it would work same way ( we are using SQL Server);

```
knex.raw(`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF`);

// SQL INSERT #1
// SQL INSERT #2
// SQL UPDATE #1
// SQL INSERT #3
// SQL INSERT #4
// SQL UPDATE #2

knex.raw(`COMMIT TRANSACTION`);
knex.raw(`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`);
```

I would pack it into some function that would call rollback if there would be an error... Would it be more or less the same?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to do it that way?

Instead of setting always `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF` for sequence of queries, which should be committed at the same time, you could actually start real transaction, where to send all insert queries and commit that real transaction in the end.

```
await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
    await trx('table').insert(...);
    await trx('table').update(...);
    await trx('table').insert(...);
    // when function returns implicit promise all the 
    // inserts and updates will be committed
    // if an exception is thrown and promise returned 
    // by this async function rejects, then transaction will be rolled back
});
```

Comment: if this code:
```global.transRaw = (...t)=>{
    let done = false;
     DB.transaction(async (trx) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        const element = t[i];
        await trx.schema.raw(element);
      }

      done = true;
    })
    while (!done) {
      deasync.sleep(3);
    }
  }

  transRaw(
    'query', ' qery', ...
  )```
will work it would be fine ... but it would be better if I can write code like the example that I wrote in the first post because we have like 1000 libs written in js from 2005 ( rhino + java)  and they have to work in nodejs

Comment: You cannot decide easily to which connection all those queries should be sent, so you would have to handle getting connection from pool and returning it back also manually to be able to run the code like in original question. It is not impossible though. But if you are going to use `knex` just to run raw SQL Server queries, then you would better off by using `tedious` driver directly.

Comment: hmmm okey how about query like this : `SELECT * FROM Serial_Numbers where id in (?) AND id_type in (?)` in knex i can use raw like `DB.raw(sql, [[1,2,3,4,5,6,667],['t1','t2','t4']])` how about `tedious` in that stuation ?